# send email through asp.net with c# coding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm new to ASP.NET with C#. Can anybody guide me on how to send an email through ASP.NET with C# using server (including configuring the server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.Net.Mail;
...

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("sender@foo.bar.com");

message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient1@foo.bar.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient2@foo.bar.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient3@foo.bar.com"));

message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("carboncopy@foo.bar.com"));
message.Subject = "This is my subject";
message.Body = "This is the content";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

in the web.config

```
 <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="test@foo.com">
    <network host="smtpserver1" port="25" userName="username" password="secret" defaultCredentials="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Thanks [Scott](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/16/432854.aspx)

Comment: hai thanx for your reply... can you please explain what is host-"smtpserver1" username="username" password="secret".... where i going to get all these...????

Comment: Google it, your can set up your own, use ur ISP's, use google/yahoo mails smtp servers.

Comment: hai paul thanx the mail send successfully but i use localhost for sending the mail. could you tell me where the mail is store in my mail???????